# Magento I want to remove the left nav

Tags: magento

I have created my own navigation as a CMS block that I am displaying in the left nav. I am still make certain categories visible in the menu so that they will show up in main navigation. However when I do that the left side nav pops back up. How can I remove this block or hide it?

```html
  <catalog_category_default translate="label">
        <label>Catalog Category (Non-Anchor)</label>
        <reference name="left">
   <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"/>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
```

this is my theme catalog.xml file. I assumed it would be to unset this block?
Magento 1.9.3.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use unsetChild to remove blocks in layout xml

```
<action method="unsetChild"><name>catalog.leftnav</name></action>
```

normally you would do this local.xml of your theme

Comment: Is there a way to do this in the XML textarea of only one category.

Comment: @NoahWetjen yes. you can put this into Custom Design -> Custom Layout update